# related to mdf files

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I found the following code in a Linq to Sql tutorial, from where Northwnd class come from? Is it generated automatically

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");

// Query for customers in London.
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;
```

Comment: Microsoft uses the fictional "Northwinds Traders Company" for all of their database tutorials. It should come with MS Office and be part of the developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generated using wizards in Visual Studio by adding a new Linq to Sql element to the project. I would recommend you the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx). And [another one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx).